# How to set the project httpport in the non-appconf beego project?

Tags: go, beego

There is an [open-source project](https://github.com/kongyuebin1/dongfeng-pay/tree/master/service):

[image]

in the application I do not find the httpport config, when I build and run it, there use the `8080`. I want to change it.  but how?

Answer (score 0):

You can change config in app.conf
[image]

Comment: there is no app.conf file/